# c++ ShutdownBlockReasonCreate return "1" and GetLastError return "2"

Tags: c++

I have a non visible application that should block log off.
I tried this code:

```
int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow){if (!FindWindow("MyWind", NULL))
{

    // Ensure that the common control DLL is loaded. 

    ghInstance = hInstance;

    WNDCLASS wc;
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;

    wc.style = 0;                                   // Class style
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC) WndProc;             // Window procedure address
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;                             
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;                              
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;                       
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);      
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW + 1); 
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;                         
    wc.lpszClassName = "MyWind";                

    RegisterClass (&wc);

    hwnd = CreateWindow (
        "MyWind",           // WNDCLASS name
        "MyWind",          // Window title
        NULL,               // Window style
        0,                  // Horizontal position
        200,                // Vertical position        
        10,                 // Initial width
        15,                 // Initial height
        HWND_DESKTOP,       // Handle of parent window
        NULL,               // Menu handle
        hInstance,          // Application's instance handle
        NULL                // Window-creation data
        );

    ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_HIDE);
    UpdateWindow (hwnd);

    int i = ShutdownBlockReasonCreate(hwnd, L"Block Shutdown");
    DWORD dwRealErrorCode = GetLastError();
    char sreason[50];
    sprintf(sreason,"%d - %ld",i,dwRealErrorCode);
    if(dwRealErrorCode != 0)
        MessageBox(NULL,sreason,"FAIL!",MB_OK);     

    while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {

        TranslateMessage (&msg);
        DispatchMessage (&msg);

    }

    ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy(hwnd);
    return Helper64::WParamTo<int>(msg.wParam);
}
else
    return 0;
```

}

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,
                      LPARAM lParam){   switch (message) {   
    //------------------------------------
case WM_QUERYENDSESSION :
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    break;
case WM_ENDSESSION:
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
```

}

the Return value of the function "ShutdownBlockReasonCreate" is "1" where the return value of GetLastError is "2"

Is there somme specific ustall or updates on windows that makes this run or no, because in other VirtualMachines (with the same configuration as my physical machine)this works perfectly.

Comment: According to the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx , if there is no error, then the return code for `ShutdownBlockReasonCreate` is non-zero.  Thus calling `GetLastError` is not valid if the return value is `1`.

Comment: Also I have not in may mchine the black block shutdownscreen when I try to logoff my session

Comment: Oki, But the problem here is that this fucntion is not working and the default windws message is not working

Comment: You cannot block a shutdown.  ShutdownBlockReasonCreate() merely displays a custom message on the shutdown screen that explains why you are delaying it.  You cannot delay forever.  Of course the user will ignore the message and click the Shutdown button anyway.

Comment: Oki but even the custom message is not dispalayed  I always get the default windows message besides I am not not getting the black UI screen that enumerate the hunging application : juste some system dialog boxes that contain all the same message